# Read Binary Data from the server

Tags: java, objective-c, xcode, inputstream, binary-data

Im looking to read the binary data coming from the java server like

```
DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());
//dos.writeInt(5);
dos.writeUTF("some text");
dos.flush();
```

And in the iOS side

```
[stream open];
Byte buffer[100];
NSMutableData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
while ([stre.stream hasBytesAvailable])
{
    int bytesRead = [stre.stream read:buffer maxLength:100];
    if(bytesRead == -1)
        continue;
   // bytesRead -= 2; //exclude the binary header
    [data appendBytes:buffer length:bytesRead];

}
[stre.stream close];

NSString * temp = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

NSLog(@"%@", temp);
```

But still unable to get the string. Is this problem is related to encoding ? And what type of encoding i can use for this issue.

@nd thing is i want to read integer, strings, UTFCharacters on iOS from the stream. Is there any way how to read the buffer i.e readInteger(), readString() and readCharacter().

Comment: You are using NSASCIIStringEncoding to decode the string, shouldn't you use NSUTF8StringEncoding?

Comment: Marcel, i tried NSUTF8StringEncoding as well but no luck. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not a expert in IOS but if you want actually to implement text based protocol use tools other than `DataOutputStream` and anyway do not use `writeUTF()`.

For pure text based protocol use

```
PrintWriter w = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(response.getOutputStream()))
```

or even just

```
PrintWriter w = response.getWriter();
```

Now writer there:

```
w.print(str);
w.println(str);
```

etc.

If you want to combine binary and string data, use `DataOutputStream.writeChars(str)`

Comment: thanks AlexR. I want to send Binary data using UTF format, in UTF it takes 1 byte for every character but if i send data through writeChars it will take 2 bytes for each character so double the bandwidth.

2nd problem is that i have to send data in localized format and i guess writeChars didnt support localized strings